# NextJs Sidebar and Navbar sticky layout

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Hi how can I make a nextjs app layout that has a sidebar and a navbar that stay in place, without scrolling. And that the children of the layout do have scroll.

Using Tailwind css and app router.

Something like this:

[Website example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knvCG.png)

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
          <body className={font.className}>
            <Navbar />
            <div>
              <Sidebar />
            </div>
            <div>
              {children}
            </div>
          </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Thanks!